# Is it ok to return reference from pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, interface, reference, virtual-functions

```
class I {
public:
  virtual std::wstring const& GetName() const = 0;
};
```

Usually clients which implement this interface contain their name inside their body. And everything works just fine. But sometimes the result of 'GetName' is calculated during function execution. Using static variable to store result is not a very good idea. But returning by value requires additional performance overhead.

So how this problem could be solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> But returning by value requires
>   additional performance overhead.

This is not true. The compiler will very often be able to elide the copy using [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: Nope. RVO doesn't work in this case. Just tested on VS 2010. http://pastebin.com/YCz6P4um

Comment: @anatoly: It doesn't work in this case, because you are not returning a local, but a member of your class. In this case, the copy can never be elided. That was not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't guess performance issues: while people often return `std::string` by const reference, it is really not a big deal to return one by value, especially if you have no other choice.

Actually, you can sometimes even change that latter as it affects only a few things for the client code.

Remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Now, to fully answer the question, you can perfectly return a reference in virtual function (whether it is pure or not doesn't really matter). Just ensure never to return a reference to a temporary.

If some derived class needs to perform a costly computation, it can still store the result in a member `std::wstring` and return a reference to that. But once again, don't guess performance issues: measure first and focus on it only if this seems to be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Though everyone else seems to agree that it is a very bad idea (for a variety of reasons, all of which are somewhat true), I don't see anything *fundamentally* wrong with returning a `string const&`.

Doing so

- is technically legitimate and will work just fine (it merely lays down a "contract" that the deriving classes must fulfill in some yet-unspecified way)
- is probably an insignificant micro-optimization (which also is likely none different from RVO in an optimized build), but it does not hurt either... insofar, so what
- does not allow the caller to modify the name, which makes sense (the caller is not competent to do so, it's why he had to ask in the first place!) -- this is semantically actually a good thing
- will work regardless of the actual yet-unknown implementation, even with temporaries (since for *const* references, the standard extends the lifetime of local variables to the lifetime of the reference)

So, although kind of unusual, if it does what you want (especially making explicit that the caller may not modify the string), I see no absolute reason not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

OK in what sense?  It's legal C++.  It's usually very poor programming
practice, for the reason you mention: it imposes a (usually) unnecessary
restriction on derived classes.  Independently of `virtual`, you should
only return a reference when the semantics of the function require it;
if the type has value semantics, like `std::string`, then this would
only be a non-const reference.  (Templates complicate the issue somewhat,
and it is reasonable for classes like `std::vector` to return a
reference to const from `operator[] const`.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bad idea. If the overhead really matters, you could use some string container with implicit sharing (copy-on-write semantics), like `QString`.

Comment: Changing to another set of overhead?